# Format file into an Excel sheet

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, csv

I am a new programmer in python, and I need your help. If I load the following url in chrome https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nhl/2016-2017-regular/cumulative_player_stats.{format}, where `{format}` could be `csv` or `json` format, then once downloaded and open, the file is already well formatted. How could I convert it into an Excel sheet in using `pandas` or `openpyxl`?

### UPDATE

```
import base64
import requests
import json

USERNAME, PASSWORD = 'notworking', 'notworking'

def send_request():
    # Request

    try:
        response = requests.get(
            url="https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nhl/2017-2018-regular/cumulative_player_stats.csv", 
            params={
                "fordate": "20171009"
            },
            headers={
                "Authorization": "Basic " +
                     base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(USERNAME,PASSWORD)\
                                      .encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')
            }
        )
        print('Response HTTP Status Code: {status_code}'.format(
            status_code=response.status_code))
        print('Response HTTP Response Body: {content}'.format(
            content=response.content))
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        print('HTTP Request failed')

    return response


import pandas as pd
import io

test = send_request().content
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(test.decode('utf-8')))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/home/jeremie/Projects/Work_Projects/NHL_project/output.xls')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
```

I am struggling with the fact that my code seems working, but no file have been created.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In SO it is required to show a piece of code you have already tried and you cannot go further from that, otherwise your question will be characterised as _too broad_.

Comment: @YannisP. Ok, I will try something, but it is pretty hard for me so far.

Comment: In your case read the csv to a DataFrame with pandas `read_csv` and then write it to Excel with `DataFrame`'s method `to_excel`.

Comment: It is hard for us to answer especially since the data are provided from an API with credentials required

Comment: @YannisP. Be aware that once connected to mysportsfeeds, it it free to download.

Comment: I updated my question, but it's still not working.

Comment: try `csv` instead of `json` and `pd.read_csv(test)`

Comment: @YannisP. I have modified my question, but the output.xls file did not show up.

Comment: Try using a full file path for your output file, and add `writer.save()` at the end.

Comment: You are right @MartinEvans.

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but wouldn't it be easier/faster to just open the CSV file in Excel?

Comment: @helb I am in test mode, but I need to add a worksheet to an existing excel workbook. Hence no, this is not the right solution.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a final `.save()` to close the Pandas Excel writer and then output the Excel file, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import os

# Set the working folder to the same folder as the script
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

test = send_request().content
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(test.decode('utf-8')))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xls')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

By setting the working folder this way, it should work equally well on a Windows PC.

Comment: I have a last demand for you. I deliver this project for a friend, but he will work with Windows instead of Linux. Instead of using the absolute path, how could I set the current directory + 'output.xls' file. Is it with `sys.path`? Could you modifiy the question so that it works. I think I will accept your answer.

Comment: Adding the full path was mainly to ensure the file was ending up where you expected. You could go back to just the filename and retest.

Comment: Could you adapt your last update to the `writer`. `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('output.xls'))))` ??

Comment: Really powerful Martin!! If you upvote my question, I will be able to upvote your answer. ;) I need 15 points to do it.